# Change source (and not local) variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, local

I'm pretty new to Java and I would like the following function to change the source variable.

```
public class DummyClass {
    public void str(String str) {
        str = "";
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "strstr";
        DummyClass classy = new DummyClass();
        classy.str(str);
        System.out.print(str);
    }

}
```

it prints "strstr" and I would like it to print nothing.

Comment: Cannot be done.  Java strings are immutable.  You can't change them, ever.

Comment: @markspace Even if it was not immutable it would change nothing, as the reference is passed by value.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking, but here goes: rather than hard-code the String, pass the value as a command line argument and change the code to use the passed argument (via `args`)

Comment: @markspace *"You can't change them, ever"* are you sure about that? ;) ...  https://github.com/tonymorris/java-trivia/blob/master/src/MutableString.java :D

Comment: If you use reflection like that, you break everything, including thread safety and the Java security model.  No sane installation will let you do that.  (You can hack a development environment to allow you to change strings, but good luck getting anyone to agree to this in production code.)

Comment: @markspace If you should do that or if someone else would allow that, is a different question. I just wanted to show that *"you can't change them"* isn't _completely_ true.